# Take a photo create two pictures in gallery

Tags: android, actionscript-3, mobile, air, camera

I try to use examples to create a photo with a camera phone (flash.media.CameraUI):
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraUI.html
http://blog.everythingflex.com/2010/09/20/air-on-android-cameraui/

Everything is working fine. But for some reason the gallery always saves two of the same shot.
I can not find the reason.

Comment: Without any code it is very hard to help.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/CameraUI.html in bottom

Comment: But that won't run by itself. How is it used in your application?

Comment: Why not? The code for the link is full-featured AS3 mobile project. It works, but somehow creates two images in the gallery instead of one.

Comment: Apologies, a bad morning, I only skimmed over it. Which trace statements are output? You don't have two of the same event listeners registered do you?